# Oracle SQL for commission per employee per week

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the sample data in an Oracle 11g database I am trying to work with to come up with a SQL query to return commission earned by each employee per week. If an employee did not earn a commission in a week, then it should display 0 as in the commission_earned column. (Assuming the week start on Monday)

SQL> select * from SALES;

```
EMPLID PRODUCT_TYPE          PRODUCTID SALE_AMOUNT COMMISSION_EARNED SALE_DATE
```

---

```
  1001 Desktop                55355251         750                45 02-MAY-16
  1002 Desktop                 2332134         600                30 02-MAY-16
  1001 Laptop                   773643        1200                65 02-MAY-16
  1003 Camera                  5546232         450                25 03-MAY-16
  1002 Printer                  445321         150                15 04-MAY-16
  1001 Printer                  445321         150                15 10-MAY-16
  1003 Camera                  5546232         450                25 10-MAY-16
```

I am trying to come up with a sql that would return the total commission earned by each employee per week. I would appreciate any help or pointers.

`WEEKOF        EMPLID COMMISSION_EARNED
02-MAY-16       1001               110
02-MAY-16       1002                45
02-MAY-16       1003                25
09-MAY-16       1001                15
09-MAY-16       1002                 0
09-MAY-16       1003                25`

I came up with the below sql but it does not display a row for emplid 1002 with commision_earned as 0 for the week starting with 09-MAY-16

`SQL> select trunc(sale_date,'IW') WEEKOF,emplid,sum(COMMISSION_EARNED) COMMISSION_EARNED from sales group by trunc(sale_date,'IW'),emplid order by  trunc(sale_date,'IW'),emplid;`

WEEKOF        EMPLID COMMISSION_EARNED
02-MAY-16       1001               110
02-MAY-16       1002                45
02-MAY-16       1003                25
09-MAY-16       1001                15
09-MAY-16       1003                25

Comment: Do you have an employee table? Does the start date of the employee impact this (i.e. should an employee have a record with 0 for a week if he hasn't started working yet)?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the rows with a `cross join` and then use `left join` to get the information from the table:

```
select w.wk, e.emplid,
       coalesce(sum(t.commission_earned), 0) as commission_earned
from (select distinct trunc(weekof, 'IW') as wk from test) w cross join
     (select distinct emplid from test) e left join
     test t
     on t.emplid = e.emplid and trunc(t.weekof, 'IW') = w.wk
group by w.wk, e.emplid
order by w.wk, e.emplid;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the suggestion. I had to modify it a little to select distinct emplid in the cross join with inline view e. Without it, the commission_earned is showing up 3X time actual value(x times the number of distinct emplids)